# Correct JSON Format For http, Correct JSON Escape Charters

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http

New to working with JSON.  Have build a Spring web-app.  Currently using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client to generate some content.

My question is, how do I format my JSON correct as to not receive an error?

Below I have included code & information that you might find helpful.

Advanced Rest Client:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Having some formatting issues with http.  Shown here:

```js
"tutorialUrls": ["https://jersey.java.net/","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jersey","http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/","https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5o5/index.html","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVvL12BnIyQ","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AueeTNJsyk"],
```

Full payload shown here:

```js
{
 "kitName": "JERSEY Kit",
 "createdDate": "9\/7\/2015",
 "createdBy": "Reed Williams",
 "description": "JERSEY: RESTful Web Services In Java",
 "category": "jersey",
 "tutorialUrls": ["https://jersey.java.net/","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jersey","http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/","https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5o5/index.html","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVvL12BnIyQ","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AueeTNJsyk"],
 "kitNotes": Jersey RESTful Web Services framework is an open source, production quality framework for developing RESTful Web Services in Java that provides support for JAX-RS APIs and serves as a JAX-RS (JSR 311 & JSR 339) Reference Implementation.
}
```

Full response shown here:

```js
{
timestamp: 1441740764717
status: 400
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
message: "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'Jersey': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@347e1916; line: 9, column: 21]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Jersey': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@347e1916; line: 9, column: 21]"
path: "/addNewKit"
}
```

Additionally, here is a screenshot of what I am working with on Advanced Rest Client:

http://screencast.com/t/47jq1T2l

This is the related Java model, StarterKitInfo.java:

```js
package com.reedwilliams.techbitstarterkit.models;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 */
public class StarterKitInfo {

 private String kitName;
 private String createdDate;
 private String createdBy;
 private String description;
 private String category;
 private List<String> tutorialUrls;
// private List<String> tutorialNotes;
 private String kitNotes;
 private String id;

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getKitName() {
  return kitName;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @param kitName
  */
 public void setKitName(String kitName) {
  this.kitName = kitName;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getCreatedDate() {
  return createdDate;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @param createdDate
  */
 public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
  this.createdDate = createdDate;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getCreatedBy() {
  return createdBy;
 }

 public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
  this.createdBy = createdBy;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @param description
  */
 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }

 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getCategory() {
  return category;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @param category
  */
 public void setCategory(String category) {
  this.category = category;
 }




// /**
//  *
//  * @return
//  */
// public List<String> getTutorialNotes() {
//  return tutorialNotes;
// }
//
// /**
//  *
//  * @param tutorialNotes
//  */
// public void setTutorialNotes(List<String> tutorialNotes) {
//  this.tutorialNotes = tutorialNotes;
// }



 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public String getKitNotes() {
  return kitNotes;
 }

 public void setKitNotes(String kitNotes) {
  this.kitNotes = kitNotes;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @return
  */
 public List<String> getTutorialUrls() {
  return tutorialUrls;
 }

 /**
  *
  * @param tutorialUrls
  */
 public void setTutorialUrls(List<String> tutorialUrls) {
  this.tutorialUrls = tutorialUrls;
 }

}
```

Comment: Add quotes here - "kitNotes": "Jersey RESTful Web Services..." All string values need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes on the last field (`kitNotes`) so it's trying to parse it as something other than a string:

```
{
 "kitName": "JERSEY Kit",
 "createdDate": "9\/7\/2015",
 "createdBy": "Reed Williams",
 "description": "JERSEY: RESTful Web Services In Java",
 "category": "jersey",
 "tutorialUrls": ["https://jersey.java.net/","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jersey","http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/","https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5o5/index.html","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVvL12BnIyQ","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AueeTNJsyk"],
 "kitNotes": "Jersey RESTful Web Services framework is an open source, production quality framework for developing RESTful Web Services in Java that provides support for JAX-RS APIs and serves as a JAX-RS (JSR 311 & JSR 339) Reference Implementation."
}
```

Comment: Do I need a comma at the end of kitNotes?  As in "....(JSR 311 & JSR 339) Reference Implementation."(HERE?)

Comment: Not if it's the last element in an object.